# can we stop redirection in mobile view

Tags: reactjs

I have 15 routes defined in my web application, if a user tries to access a wrong URL, I have defined a redirection in the route with below code.
This is working perfectly.

Now I want to stop that redirection if the width of the screen is bigger than `max-width:992px`. Can we do that in reactjs?

Just for mobile view? I mean, a user will not use the complete url in mobile.

Can any one help on this?

```
<Route render={() => <Redirect exact to={{ pathname: "/" }} />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do it:

This checks the window for the width and sets `isMobile` state based on the window's width. As always, this makes sure to remove the event listener on unmount to cleanup the effect. You should be able to add other boolean flags (or just have the state be a string) for other breakpoints you are interested in.

Another thing to note is that you might want to debounce the onResize function as it is called far too quickly and could be a performance concern if you have a lot of logic that it is performing. I think it should be fine as is currently since React doesn't re-render if the state is the same as it was previously.

```
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const checkSize = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth < 992) {
        setIsMobile(true);
      } else {
        setIsMobile(false);
      }
    };
    const onResize = () => {
      checkSize();
      console.log("resized");
    };
    checkSize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", onResize);
    };
  }, []);
```

Then all you need to do is conditionally render your Route (or Redirect)

```
      {isMobile && (
        <Route>
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Route>
      )}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/redirection-in-mobile-view-i14xx?file=/example.js